# Flagging accepted "answers"

Tags: discussion, flags, accepted-answer

While reviewing I came upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005823/507519) by the OP of the question. I believe it was meant to be a comment to another post or comment that I have not been able to identify. Normally I would have flagged this as "Not an answer" and moved on.

But...

For whatever reason, most probably due to not understanding how SO works, the OP marked this post as the accepted answer. I have to admit that this is a first for me - I've never felt the urge to flag an *accepted* answer before, but I find myself being far more cautious at the sight of that green checkmark.

- *Should I treat accepted answers like this any differently?* Accepting an answer usually (although probably not in this case) means that it is the final word on the issue at hand as far as the OP is concerned, which is why I am reluctant to flag it.
- *What happens to a question if the accepted answer is deleted?* E.g. is it placed back into the *Unanswered* pile? What about the accept-points for its poster?

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the "answer." If anyone cares, here is what it looked like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVA3v.png

Comment: @ProblematicTitleException: Thanks! Sometimes I wonder if posts like this would make a good source of entropy for my RNG...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I treat accepted answers like this any differently?

In my opinion, no.  Some users accept answers that are clearly useless, for any number of reasons.  One reason is to silence the critics who complain about their accept rate.

> What happens to a question if the accepted answer is deleted? E.g. is
>   it placed back into the Unanswered pile?

Yes, if there are no other answers with upvotes.

> What about the accept-points for its poster?

They are removed at the user's next reputation recalc.  But that's a good outcome, if the answer was useless to begin with.

Comment: +1 for a complete answer. I do have a question, though: are the accept-points - the whole two of them - really removed at the next recalc, rather than automatically? What would happen if a question poster accepted another answer afterwards?

Comment: The score at the top of the page is cached between recalcs. It doesn't immediately take into account points lost due to deletions. The new accepted answer would immediately add an additional 2 rep to the accepter's displayed rep score.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I treat accepted answers like this any differently?

No, you should not. If you think that the answer is not useful, you can down-vote it; if you think the answer is not really an answer (as in this case, where it should have been a comment), you can flag it as "not an answer."

> What happens to a question if the accepted answer is deleted?

If there is another up-voted answer, nothing happens to the question, which is still considered answered; what reported in the "unanswered" tab are questions without an up-voted answer, which includes also the case the question doesn't have any answer at all.